# Javascript Snake Game: How to get apple to disappear from board and re-appear somewhere new when contact is made

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am having a hard time figuring out how to get the apple to disappear and re-appear somewhere new when it comes in contact with the snake. I understand that this is probably happening because the apple is being redrawn every second(or fraction of) inside a drawEverything() function that is drawing all the game pieces over and over - snake, grid, apple, etc... I have been able to figure out how to detect when the snake touches the apple, but I just am having the damnedest time figuring out how to get the original apple drawn to disappear and pop up somewhere new. I tried setting it outisde the drawEverything() function but then it doesn't appear. I'm guessing because it is being drawn over - over and over by the drawEverything() function. The closest I have gotten is that the apple will flicker, as if it wants to disappear and then a new apple will pop up randomly for a fraction of a second and then disappear while the original apple doesn't move. any help is much appreciated. Below is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
    window.onload = function() {
  //drawCanvas();

  setInterval(function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(drawEverything);
  }, 1000 / fps);
};

function drawEverything() {
  canvas = document.querySelector("#gameCanvas");
  canvas.width = 800;
  canvas.height = 600;
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
  //draws game canvas
  colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "black");

  // //draws the snake
  colorRect(snakeX, snakeY, 20, 20, "green");

  //appleSpawn();
  drawGrid();
  moveSnake();
  appleSpawn();
}

function moveSnake() {
  snakeY -= snakeSpeedY; //move up
  snakeX += snakeSpeedX; //move right

  if (snakeX >= canvas.width - snakeEdge) {
    //remember 15 is size of snake. maybe make variable for this
    snakeSpeedX = -snakeSpeedX;
    //gameOver();
  }
  if (snakeX < 0) {
    snakeSpeedX = -snakeSpeedX;
  }
  if (snakeY >= canvas.height - snakeEdge) {
    snakeSpeedY = -snakeSpeedY;
    //gameOver();
  }
  if (snakeY < 0) {
    snakeSpeedY = -snakeSpeedY;
  }

  if (snakeX == randomX && snakeY == randomY) {
    console.log("score", score);
    score++;
    canvasContext.clearRect(randomX, randomY, 20, 20);
    newApple();
  }
}

function newApple() {
  let randomX = gridSquareWidth * Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasColumn);
  let randomY = gridSquareHeight * Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasRow);
  colorRect(randomX, randomY, 20, 20, "red");
}

function appleSpawn() {
  colorRect(randomX, randomY, 20, 20, "red");
//this line calls to another function that fills in coordinates, size and color of the apple
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't have to 'manually' remove your apple instance from screen.

If you take a look at the **drawEverything()** function - which gets called over and over again using requestAnimationFrame - you'll spot the following line:

```
colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "black");
```

This tints the whole game screen in plain black. So everything that has been there is now erased.

A few lines later your snake is drawn using:

```
colorRect(snakeX, snakeY, 20, 20, "green");
```

and finally the apple using:

```
appleSpawn();
```

which is just another call to the **colorRect** function - which draws a rectangle at the specified coordinates.
colorRect(randomX, randomY, 20, 20, "red");

Now if your snake hits that apple it will invoke the following function:

```
function newApple() {
  let randomX = gridSquareWidth * Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasColumn);
  let randomY = gridSquareHeight * Math.floor(Math.random() * canvasRow);
  colorRect(randomX, randomY, 20, 20, "red");
}
```

The problem is the **let** keyword here. This makes randomX and randomY local variables inside that function - **appleSpawn()** though uses randomX and randomY from a global scope - which hasn't changed. So just get rid of **let** and the call to colorRect. It isn't needed because it will be called inside drawEverything anyway.

Here's a small example to visualize the problem - just hit the 'Run code snippet' button:

```js
var randomX = 12;

function check() {
  let randomX = 2;
}
function check2() {
  randomX = 5;
}
check();
console.log(randomX);
check2();
console.log(randomX);
```

Comment: wow, nice eye! thank you so much. i knew it could be something so simple. i am new to javascript and spent many hours perplexed by this. you rock!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words mokate - glad I could help! =)